# MySQL slow join

Tags: mysql, join

I have a MySQL query that is taking ages to run when I join to a second table.

My 2 tables are as follows:

```
Table        Rows
properties   51,000
details      3,700,000
```

My SQL statement is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.id, a.address1, a.address2, a.address3, a.address4, a.address5, a.original_price, a.price, a.create_date, a.description, a.status, a.street, a.postcode, a.type_flag, AVG(coalesce(b.price,0)) as avg_price, coalesce((a.price - AVG( b.price )),0) AS difference, a.url, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, DATE(a.create_date), now()) as months, a.distance, a.expired, a.favourite
FROM properties a
LEFT JOIN details b ON a.street = b.street AND a.postcode = b.sector AND a.type_flag = b.type
WHERE a.price >= '0' AND a.price <= '200000' AND a.expired = 'N' AND a.status != 'R' AND a.flag = 'R'
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY  a.address1 asc
LIMIT 0, 50
```

I have the following indexes on table properties:

```
Index          Keys
status         status, flag
expired        expired
full_key       street, postcode, type_flag, expired, status, flag
```

and the following index on table details:

```
Index          Keys
address        type, street, sector
```

When I run the SQL statement with explain, I get:

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys   key      key_len  ref                       rows   Extra  
1   SIMPLE       a      ref   status,expired  expired  5        const                     14766  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE       b      ref   address         address  417      property.a.type_flag,     4
                                                                property.a.street,
                                                                property.a.postcode
```

Do you think I should force this query to use  the index 'full_key'?
Or do you think I need to create a new index altogether?

When I run this without the join, it runs quickly, so it seems to be the join to the large details table that is slowing it down.

The problem I have with testing is once I've run the query once, next time it runs really quickly so I have to wait a day before I can test again.

### Update

These are the table schemes

properties table:

```
Column           Type   
id               int(15)
agent            varchar(64)
street           varchar(128)
town             varchar(64)
county           varchar(64)
postcode         varchar(16)
type_flag        varchar(1) 
price            decimal(12,2)
status           varchar(1)
address1         varchar(128)
address2         varchar(128)
address3         varchar(128)
address4         varchar(128)
address5         varchar(128)
description      varchar(512)
type             varchar(32)
bedrooms         varchar(16)
flag             varchar(1)
expired          varchar(1)
favourite        varchar(1)
```

details table:

```
Column           Type
id               varchar(128)
price            decimal(12,2)
date             datetime
postcode         varchar(16)
type             varchar(1)
old_new          varchar(1)
duration         varchar(1)
paon             varchar(32)
saon             varchar(32)
street           varchar(128)
locality         varchar(128)
town_city        varchar(128)
local_authority  varchar(128)
county           varchar(128)
status           varchar(1)
sector           varchar(8)
```

UPDATE 2:

After changing the 'expired' index to expired, flag, status, price the query still runs extremely slowly.

Here's what I get when I do the explain now:

```
id   select_type  table  type    possible_keys      key       key_len   ref                   rows    extra
1    SIMPLE       a      range   status,expired     expired   16        NULL                  1031    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1    SIMPLE       b      ref     address            address   417       property.a.type_flag, 4
                                                                        property.a.street,
                                                                        property.a.postcode
```

So the number of rows from table properties has gone down from 14,766 to 1,031 but the query took 127.1271 seconds to run.

Is it possible to get this query running quickly or is MySQL useless when it comes to joining to large tables?

Comment: It runs quickly the second time because mysql caches the results from the first run. Just add SQL_NO_CACHE after the select when testing  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-in-select.html

Comment: Really do not understand the relationship between properties and details. What is in each one and how are they related? Perhaps the full table schemes would help people anser this.

Comment: Hi David, I've just added the table schemes.

Comment: What is the details table for and why are there so many more rows in it than in the properties table? Why is the address half-duplicated in both tables for instance? If details are details of a property then why not have a foreign key to make the join?

Comment: There is a one to many relationship between properties and details - 1 properties record can have many details records. The details table is supplied by a 3rd party so I can't change the layout of that. The only link between the 2 tables is postcode (actually it's just postal sector), street and property type

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  . . .
FROM properties p LEFT JOIN
     details d
     ON p.street = d.street AND p.postcode = d.sector AND p.type_flag = d.type
WHERE p.price >= '0' AND p.price <= '200000' AND
      p.expired = 'N' AND p.status <> 'R' AND p.flag = 'R'
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.address1 asc
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

The best indexes are something like:  `properties(expired, flag, price, status)` or  `properties(expired, flag, status, price)` and `details(street, sector, type)`.  You have the latter index.

However, your indexes for `properties` are not particularly helpful for the `where` clause.  The index that it is using is only for the `status` condition.  You have many other conditions in the `where` clause that the index could be used for.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, so should I create 2 indexes on properties - index 1: street, postcode, flag_type. Index 2: expired, status, flag. Would you include price in any of the indexes?

Comment: You don't need the first index for this query.  You need an index that works for the `where` clause.  `price` is in both indexes suggested in the answer.

Comment: I've added the expired, flag, status, price index and the row count on properties went down from 51,000 to just over 1000 so it looks promising! I'll give it a proper test tomorrow and if everything looks good I'll accept your answer Gordon. Thanks

Comment: Hi Gordon, unfortunately changing the key to expired, flag, status, price didn't work. See UPDATE 2 in my original question. Is getting this query to run quickly even possible?

Comment: @Damian . . . I suspect the issue is `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.  MySQL has to generate the entire result set, and that is probably slowing it down.

Comment: @Gordon....I tried again without the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS. Query took 112.8537 sec so slightly better, but still taking ages!